# How to go to declaration?

Tags: delphi

Delphi XE2 starter for me, but maybe a general answer will help others ...

In NetBeans I can hover my curosr over a variable or function call and press ctrl+B to go to its declaration .... how do I do that in Delphi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the same in Delphi by a simple `ctrl-click`

Comment: In Delphi XE2 starter that only works for stuff you wrote yourself. The source for the default (VCL) units, to my big surprise, are not available and thus ctrl-click won't work for them.

Comment: @Marck, it works for stuff where the sources are available - obviously.

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl-Click on name

[Online help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts) contains many other useful things

Comment: Am I the only one who curses Delphi out silently when the hourglass (or spinning circle, these days) takes over and won't go away for 60+ seconds? Argh!

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-LeftClick (and I have to add some more dummy text otherwise StackOverflow does not accept my post)

Comment: You could go into a bit more detail, for example, placing a link such as MBo above.

Comment: I have answered his question. What does a link add?

Comment: Something other than dummy text :P

Comment: Got it ;-) Even now SA said "5 more to go..."